# Where (which file) to add code to handle passing enum data to combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, enums

I'm creating a simple user registration form with fields to enter `first name`, `last name`, `user name`, `password`, and two combobox drop downs for `major` and `concentration`.
I believe I understand how to pass the enum data to the `ComboBox`, but not sure where (while file) to add the code.
Do I double click the `ComboBox` and add it there?
Do I create another class, add the enum data and code to display that data in the combobox there?

I believe I found out the way to add, here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public enum MajorList { Engineering = 1, Science, Humanities, Art, Business };
    public enum EngConcentrations { Mechanical = 1, Electrical, Chemical, Civil };
    public enum SciConcentrations { Computer, Biology };
    public enum HumConcentrations { English, History };
    public enum ArtConcentrations { Graphics, Painting, History, Music };
    public enum BusConcentrations { Administration, Economics, Accounting };

    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MajorList)))
        {
            majors.Items.Add(item);
        }            
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to add one of the other enum based off of which major I selected?
For example,  I select Engineering, and the second combobox would have the drop down of the Engineering concentrations?

Comment: Hi @GrantWinney I added the code which added the majors to the combobox.  I added a follow up questions at the end if you are able to help.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you solved your original question. That code will add the values you want, and placing it in the form's `Load` event is fine.

As for the second question, yes, you could switch a second `ComboBox` based on the value selected in the "major" `ComboBox`. Subscribe to the `SelectedValueChanged` event:

```
void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedMajor = (MajorList)comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    switch (selectedMajor)
    {
        case MajorList.Art:
            // populate the second combo box with ArtConcentrations values
            break;

        case MajorList.Business:
            // populate the second combo box with BusConcentrations values
            break;

        ...
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help with the second combobox. 
You said that, "placing it in the form's Load even is fine."  Is there a different area you'd place it, or could I create a new event on its own to add the values?